# How to create a linux image file

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, diskimage

I want to do some kernel development, and have downloaded the latest version from kernel.org, done changes, and compiled it. So far everything went well. Now I want to run it in User-Mode-Linux, so I can test it.

I have found [this site](http://fs.devloop.org.uk/) which provides a bunch of images, but non really worked. One was read-only, one was always printing error messages, another would hang on every 'halt' and some simply didn't work.

I have tried making my own image with `dd if=/dev/zero of=img count=2M`, but turns out that the empty image is not a good idea.

So my question, how can I create my own image and make it runnable?
Alternatively, where can I find an image that functions well?

Comment: what do you mean an empty image is not a good idea? What have you tried?  Also any of the images at fs.devloop.org.uk should work as a base image for you.  Do you know how to mount images?

Comment: The [User-Mode-Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/) page suggests a bootable image. Did you try it? The download link is in the "Getting started" section, along with instructions.

Comment: @AhmedMasud 'not a good idea' means it doesn't work. I have tried several images from the site, and the empty image. The link that I have put in the question is the same as you suggested.

Comment: @jweyrich The 'getting started' section leads the the same link.

Comment: Did you build UML from the kernel you picked? Finally, if you followed the official instructions correctly and still got into problems, I guess you should somehow report a bug/problem to the maintainers/developers. That's not the answer (if an answer at all) you might be expecting, but getting the developers to reproduce this problem will actually evolve the project as a whole and help beginners getting it to work more easily. Hopefully the next time someone tries it, it will work out of the box.